# the idea of the reviving the old-fashioned western

Tags: articles

I read an example in "Merriam Webster dictionaries" which was:

> Movie audiences have effectively nixed the idea of **the** reviving the old-fashioned western by emphatically ignoring this latest effort.

Is the article "the" that precede "reviving" redundant here?

Comment: Yes, it should not be there and may be an error on the webpage. There are other ways to fix the sentence too, such as saying "the reviving of the old-fashioned western...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the question a formal answer using the content of Astralbee's comment.

> Yes, it should not be there and may be an error on the webpage. There are other ways to fix the sentence too, such as saying "the reviving of the old-fashioned western...".